# Sums and products of n values in tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I have a table like

```
n    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 ...
3    2  3  6  0  0  ...
4    2  3  7  42 0  ...
5    ...
6    ...
...
```

Suppose we have 4 numbers `x1,x2,x3,x4` (case `"n=4"`).
Then the sums of all possible products of the first 1, 2 or 3 numbers have to be calculated where by definition `N(1)=1`.

I use names `N(1), N(2), N(3),...`; then in detail:

```
Case "n=3". 
given: (x1,x2,x3) = (2,3,6)
to calc:
N(1) = 1
N(2) = x1 + x2


Case "n=4". 
given: (x1,x2,x3,x4) = (2,3,7,42)
to calc:
N(1) = 1
N(2) = x1 + x2
N(3) = x1·x2 + x1·x3 + x2·x3 

Case "n=5". 
given: (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = (....)
to calc:
N(1) = 1
N(2) = x1 + x2
N(3) = x1·x2 + x1·x3 + x2·x3 
N(4) = x1·x2·x3 +x1·x2·x4 +x1·x3·x4 +x2·x3·x4

.... .... .... ....
```

How could I do that? With `\usetikzlibrary{math}` maybe?
What is the best point to start?

Not really an MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\List{1,2,3}
%\def\Array{\List}

\tikzmath{
int \i;
for \i in \List {
\N{\i} = (\i)*0.5;
\N{3}=555;
};
}

\node{ \N{3} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what's the formula for the entries? your ascii art has sums of possibly negated products, and the sketch code is multiplying things by 0.5 I don't see a common pattern anywhere?

Comment: Sorry - typo. It is always plus in the ASCII-art...

Comment: but even then I can't guess what you are adding up.

Comment: is N(i) the sum of the (n choose i-1 )products of i-1 elements of the original list?

Comment: Eh, yes..........................

Comment: Suppose we have 4 numbers x1,x2,x3,x4.
Then the sums of all possible products of the first 1, 2 or 3 numbers have to be calculated (these are the names N(1), N(2), N(3)); where by definition N(1)=1.

Comment: yes it's just a simple recursive definition should be easy to write using l3 int and clist mapping functions, I may look later

Comment: Yes, the question is, how do I best set this up: I could imagine using the TikZ math-library; instead of normal foreach and pgfmath. But there I'm having no idea for calculating the sums.

Comment: I'd use L3 not pgf but maybe that's just me

Comment: so N(1)(X)=1, N(i)(X1...Xi)=X1*N(i-1)(X2...Xi) + product(X2...Xi)    ?

Comment: N(1)(X1...Xi) = 1, N(k)(X1...Xi) = Xk*N(k-1)(X1...Xi) + product(X1...Xk-1) ?

Comment: I think my formulation is probably correct but it contradicts your "eh, yes" answer to my initial guess, so just checking...  N(i,list) just uses the first i elements all later elements are ignored? (the description and implementation would actually be easier if the function didn't have the first argument and you just implied that by the list ie define  N(i,list)=M(first-i-elements-of-list) then you could define M(singleton)=1 M(head,rest)=head*M(rest)+product(rest)

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not entirely clear on the intended formula but I think this implements

N(i,list) just uses the first i elements, all later elements are ignored so we can define

```
define N(i,list)=M(first-i-elements-of-list) 

define M(singleton)=1,
       M(head,rest)=head*M(rest)+product(rest)
```

The following recursive definition of M works by expansion so can be used with symbolic input `(x,y,z)` or with numeric input i produces an expression that may be evaluated by `\inteval`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% 
\cs_new:Npn\cis_clist_rest:n#1{
  \cis_clist:aux:w#1
}
\cs_new:Npn\cis_clist:aux:w#1,{  }

\cs_new:Npn\cis_M:n#1 {
  \int_case:nnF {\clist_count:n{#1}}
      {{1}{1}}
      {
        \clist_item:nn{#1}{1} * (\cis_M:e{\cis_clist_rest:n{#1}})+
            \clist_use:en{\cis_clist_rest:n{#1}}{*}
        }
      }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\clist_use:nn {en}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\cis_M:n {e}

\let\cisM\cis_M:n
            
\ExplSyntaxOff

\parskip\baselineskip

\hrule
M(z) \quad       \cisM{z}

\hrule
M(y,z)\quad      \cisM{y,z}

\hrule
M(x,y,z)\quad      \cisM{x,y,z}

\hrule
M(2)\quad      \inteval{\cisM{2}}

\hrule
M(2,3)\quad       \inteval{\cisM{2,3}}


\hrule
M(2,3,7)\quad       \inteval{\cisM{2,3,7}}

\hrule
M(2,3,7,42)\quad       \inteval{\cisM{2,3,7,42}}

\hrule


\end{document}
```